# Can you use rmagic (rpy2) in google colaboratory?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I know google colaboratory doesn't yet support an R kernel.  What about rmagic? Can I use `rpy2`?

I tried :

```
!pip install rpy2==2.8.6
```

And got :

```
Collecting rpy2==2.8.6
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/32/54/d102eec14f9cabd0df60682a38bd45c36169a1ec8fb8a690bf436cb6d758/rpy2-2.8.6.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Error: Tried to guess R's HOME but no command 'R' in the PATH.

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-3bSiiD/rpy2/
```

I'm guessing that it isn't working because R isn't installed on whatever cloud machine this notebook is running on, and that it probably isn't possible to install it. But I'm hoping I'm wrong and someone may know of a work around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I answered my own question.  I thought for sure this would fail, but tried anyway:

```
!apt-get update
!apt-get install r-base
!pip install rpy2==2.8.6
```

And it worked!

Comment: If you want to use rpy2 now, I'd recommend using the latest release (at the time of writing this is 2.9.4).

Comment: Thanks, @lgautier.  I believe only python 3 is supported in rpy2 beyond 2.9.x. I needed python 2.7, but this is a good tip for others using python 3.

Comment: @kmartin can you add some more sample code showing how you went on to use rpy2?  eg did you then do %load_ext rpy2.ipython ? (which is not working for me right now)  thanks!